# rails blind index gem raw sql query not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used `lockbox` gem to encrypt the column values and `blind_index` to query.

This is working:

```
User.where(first_name: 'John')
```

Not working:

```
User.where("first_name = ? ", 'John') 

User.where("first_name_bidx = ? ", 'John') // Absolutely this should'nt work.
```

`blind_index` works very well for rails standard way, but not working with sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Blind Index gem is not able to parse SQL strings to understand `first_name = ?` means you want to do `first_name_bidx = computed_bidx_value`. Instead, use:

```rb
User.where("first_name_bidx = ?", User.generate_first_name_bidx("John"))
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, for the answer. As you said in the gem documentation, LIKE query not supporting. I want to search full name of encrypted data, with LIKE query. is there any way?

Comment: I just added a section to the Blind Index readme on the topic: https://github.com/ankane/blind_index#like-ilike-and-fuzzy-searching